# How to run intern framework on browser

Tags: javascript, testing, intern

I am new to intern framework and the project that I am working on has a unique directory structure. The intern test is a different project itself. 
The directory of intern project looks like

```
internProject/
   funtional/
   unit/
   node_modules/
       intern/
          configFiles...
   gruntfile.js
   package.json
```

The main app project is different and the directory looks like

```
<Project>
    WebContent/
      scripts/
        dojo/
        dijit/
        dojox/
```

After reading alot of documentation on how to intern on browser most of the time client.html file was on the server. In my case where the intern is a different project itself how do I run the unit test on browser ?  I need a starting point and the right direction to look into. Please let me know if you need to see the config files or something else. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [`basePath` configuration option](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#common-config) for Intern 3.  Both the `client.html` and whatever project you are testing will need to be served up by a web server.